# Paging in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datasource, paging

I have a table called A with 15 rows. I have used **paging concept** to display only 5 rows at initial load. Once the user clicks on next it will display me another 5 rows.
Now I'm gonna select any one or two rows and from table 'A' to table 'B'. 
Now I need to implement the same paging concept in Table B, i.e if the user selects any thing more than 5 rows from table 'A' it should limit the display to 5 rows in table 'B' and user should only be able to view the 6 th row by click on next button.

I have tried with different possible ways but I am failing to achieve it 
Can any one help me out?

I have placed my code snippet for selecting a row from Table A by selecting a row and displaying it in Table B

```
  private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection selectedRows = dgvFormFieldsView.SelectedRows;
        dgvFormFieldsView.ClearSelection();

          if (selectedRows.Count == 0)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("No rows selected!", "PDF Perform Warning");
            return;
          }
          for (int i = selectedRows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          {
                string fieldLabel = null;
                string fieldType = null;
                string tabOrder = null;

                tabOrder = (string)selectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                fieldLabel = (string)selectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                fieldType = (string)selectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value;

                DataRow newRow = selectedFieldsTable.NewRow();
                newRow["Field Name"] = fieldLabel;
                newRow["Field Type"] = fieldType;

                if (!selectedFieldsTable.Rows.Contains(new System.Object[] { fieldType, fieldLabel }))
                {
                    selectedFieldsTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Form Field :" + fieldLabel + " already selected", "PDF Perform Info");
                }
            }
            dgvSelectedFieldsView.DataSource = selectedFieldsTable;
            dgvSelectedFieldsView.ClearSelection();
            applyFormattingSelectedFieldsTable();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSelectedFieldsView.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = fieldValueDefaultBackColor;
                row.Cells[2].Style.SelectionBackColor = fieldValueSelectionBackColor;
            }
            if (ConfigParams.mode == Mode.Extract || ConfigParams.mode == Mode.Compare)
                dgvSelectedFieldsView.Columns["Field Value"].ReadOnly = true;
    }
```

Can any one help me out Please !!
Thanks!!!!!!